# Changes on web server (apache) web page from a container doesn't take affect

Tags: apache, docker

I created a docker container with `httpd` image:

```
sudo docker run -dt -p 8080:80 httpd
```

I verified it works by entering: http://localhost:8080

I opened shell inside the container:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

I changed the default webpage's content (`index.html`) which located in:

```
/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

I wanted to see the new changes but when I refreshed the page nothing happen.
I restarted the container and it still shows the default web page.
I am trying to restart the `httpd` service within the container's shell but without success, this is what I tried (based on [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/)):

```
# sudo service apache2 restart
  apache2: unrecognized service
# service httpd restart
  httpd: unrecognized service
# systemctl start apache2.service
  Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
  bash: /etc/init.d/apache2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a cache problem with FireFox.
I opened it on private browsing and it worked.

A good way to verify it is by running:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

I will return updated GET request.